# Google Maps adding multiple markers using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

> So this set of code is pulling in locations (Latitude, Longitude, and Address) from a C# backend.
>   the backend code pulls data from a SQL database and inputs it into the ASP.Net DataField columns.
>   It was an enhancement to a prebuilt application to include Google Maps.
>   The locations pull just fine and stepping through it shows the latitude and longitude correctly.
>   The issue I'm having is that only one marker shows up which looks to be the last one.
>   Its as if each location isn't actually adding a new marker, but overwriting the current one which leaves the last location as the marker on the map.
>   What do I need to change to get each location to show up as a new marker?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function locate() {
        var inputList = GridView1.getElementsByTagName("td");
        var rows = GridView1.getElementsByTagName("tr");
       // var markers = inputList[0].innerHTML;
        for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var lat = rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
            var lng = rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
            var addr = rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML, rows[1].cells[3].innerHTML),
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var markers = [];
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            var data = rows[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.cells[2].innerHTML, data.cells[3].innerHTML);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.cells[1].innerHTML);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're creating the map and the marker within the same loop.   i.e. you're creating a map with a single marker on it, `rows ` times.  You want to create the map outside of your loop.

Comment: Also in JS arrays are zero-indexed. Do you maybe want to change your loop to start at `i=0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the map and the marker within the same loop. i.e. you're creating a map with a single marker on it, rows times. You want to create the map outside of your loop.  Something like this:

```
function locate() {
    var rows = GridView1.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML, rows[1].cells[3].innerHTML),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

    for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var data = rows[i];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.cells[2].innerHTML, data.cells[3].innerHTML);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map
        });
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.cells[1].innerHTML);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that.  Good looking out.